# Is it possible to sort formula results?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, vba

i have sheet with formulas which results depending on multiple columns, where each data row contains attributes of some measurement. And i need to sort formula results.

When i try something like this, it sorts nothing. I even thought about sorting source data, but i need to sort them by formula result...

```
Sub formulaSort()
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With testSheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(18, 4)).Sort key1:=.Range("D2"), order1:=xlAscending


    End With

End Sub
```

So is here some option how to sort formula results, or multiple data columns by formula result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i was very dumb, so maybe this will help someone in future. Sort data based on formula result is easy as love. Just select all data and formulas and sort them based on formula column....

```
Sub formulaSort()
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rangeToSort As Range



    With testSheet

        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(18, 4)).Sort key1:=.Range("D2"), order1:=xlAscending


    End With

End Sub
```